# What is an integral with a higher order differential? d^3 v

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Pauli's lectures on statistical mechanics start out with:

> Let $
> f(v) d^3 v 
> $ be the number of molecules with velocity contained in $ d^3 v $, and let $n=\int f(v)d^3 v$ be the number of molecules per $cm^3$. The function $f(v)$ can also depend on $x$. Then we have 
>   $$ \int \int f(v,x)d^3v d^3 x=\int n(x)d^3x=N $$ where N is the total number of molecules.

I was wondering what is meant by the integrals with the higher order differentials. I've never seen one in that form, unless it is short hand for integrating the velocity and position in 3 dimensions.

Comment: $d^3v$ is a shorthand for $dv_1 dv_2 dv_3$. The velocity of each molecules contributes 3 components. It is preferable to collect all these 3 related components under one notation. Less indices means less distraction to the important part in the integral.

Comment: Thanks much Hui, I'm glad it turned out to be so simple.

Answer (score 1):

$\int n(x) d^3x$ means $\int\int\int n(x_1,x_2,x_3) dx_1 dx_2 dx_3$.  It is just notation.